# Broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android

I have implemented simple message(xmpp protocol) application using smack api.there are number activities which are receiving notification when incoming message comes.now i want to notify my application when the incoming message comes even the application is not running.By reading documentation i know that this is achieved by Broadcast receiver.But how to adopt this to my application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the broadcast receiver to do this.

In you androidmanifest.xml for eg: consider this activity.

```
<activity android:name=".activity.message"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:launchMode="singleInstance">

<intent-filter>   
 <action android:value="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />                   
</intent-filter>

 </activity>
```

Once you add the intent to the activity's intent filter list in android.xml,whenever that intent is thrown your activity will be invoked irrespective of whether it is open or not.

Here the intent you would want to add to listen for incoming messages would be

```
 <action android:value="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
```

I think you also need to have permissions for this so add this also to your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission id="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Comment: Whatever the case is you just need to add the intent action to your actvity's intent filter tag.I have mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: Even for the broadcast receiver the same thing is applicable but that is not what you want in your case.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html--
Read on "Declaring component capabilities".